# foreach ending before going through all of the list

Tags: c#, database, foreach, datagridview

When running the code, it only goes through a small part of the rows in tableSiblings.Rows

I also tried using for instead of foreach (of course change the inside of the ()) but it still didn't work.
What can I Do?

```
dsSiblings = dal.GetDataSet("Select * From Siblings");
// Go through the table:
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tableSiblings.Rows)
{
    // If this is a new row:
    if ((row.Cells["siblingID"].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString() == string.Empty.ToString())
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        // Go through the database:
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsSiblings.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // If a sibling with the same ID exists:
            if ((row.Cells["siblingID"].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString() == dr["siblingID"].ToString())
            {
                DoSomethingElse();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
dal.UpdateDataSet(dsSiblings);
```

Comment: You are initializing a `dsSiblings` but then loop through a `tableSiblings`. Where does `tableSiblings` get initialized? Why are you not using a SELECT with a JOIN instead?

Comment: tableSiblings is already initialized. It loops through both of the tables but it won't finish going though the tableSiblings.